# Weird compilation issues

Tags: c, compilation

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <math.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
int rev (int N);
int rev(int N){
return ((N <= 9)) ? N : rev(N / 10) + ((N % 10) * (pow(10, (floor(log10(abs(N))))))) ;
}
int main(void){
    int r, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    r = rev(n);
    printf("%d %d", r, n);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A simple code just to find out the reverse of a number. Everything is fine. Until I put a number with more than 2 digits. Things behave weirdly, somehow the last digit is always 0 of the reversed number. I have checked out in online compilers where things behave just fine. However the problem arises when I run the code on my own machine. I am on `Windows 10` with `MINGw`. Could you guys suggest me a solution. I previously had problems where the value stored in an `int` matrix changes to huge values which is practically impossible to store in `int` due to it's size.

Comment: cant reproduce on cent os

Comment: Working fine on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: try separating that big expression into small expressions and see you can find something

Comment: 'A simple code'??  Ahem....'return ((N <= 9)) ? N : rev(N / 10) + ((N % 10) * (pow(10, (floor(log10(abs(N))))))) '.    That makes step-debugging much more difficult than it should be:(

Comment: Don't expect `log10()` and `pow()` to give you nice clean integer results. If you are reversing an integer, work with integers. If you must use those functions, add `round()` into the mix too, instead of `floor()`. Otherwise, it's far simpler to build an integer with `n = n * 10 + digit;`

Comment: You declare the function, then immediately define it? Just define it.

Comment: I changed a bit of the code to `floor(log10(n))`. `log10(n)` might not  return a clean integer, however I used a floor to convert it to the nearest lower integer. Still no solution. Can YOU suggest me an algorithm for reversing a number that uses recursion , doesn't use any looping mechanism or any other math function that returns a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pow and floor function, working with floats will not always round the way you'd expect.

As already commented, work with integers.

Propose doing this digit-by-digit, and sticking with integers. A proposal for your rev() function:

```
int rev(unsigned int N)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    while(N>0)
    {
        // pick off lowest digit
        unsigned int digit = N%10;
        // put into result, moving up all previous digits by doing *10
        res = 10*res+digit;
        // remove this digit from input value
        N/=10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I did this using while loop and recursion, however my teacher wants a recursive function without using any kind of loops.